# How to get the text between <b>text</b> in userscript

Tags: javascript

I have the source code as...

```
<div class="pd10 tbg2 cbl tcnt" style="line-height: 26px;">
<b>Opps ! please try again</b>
</div>
```

I want to search for this pattern on the webpage & if the text is found do some job
So..I wrote the script as...

```
    if (path == "/dash/process/")
    {
        var content=document.getElementsByTagName('b')[0].innerHTML;
        var pat="Opps";

        if(content.search(pat)<0)
        {
            //do some job
        }
             else
              {
               //do some job
              }
     }
```

Is it correct..?
please help me in solving this....

Comment: `pat` is expected to be a regular expression, not a string. Better use `indexOf` instead of `search`

Comment: "*Is it correct?*" - We don't know. Does it work for you? Do you have any problems? Then ask specifically about them. If it's working, this question should be moved to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (path == "/dash/process/")
{
    var content=document.getElementsByTagName('b')[0].innerHTML;
    var pat="Opps";

    if(content.indexOf(pat) != -1)
    {
        //do some job
    }
    else
    {
        //do some job
    }
}
```

In the above code `indexOf` returns a value of -1 when what you're looking for in the string cannot be found. In this case, the if is checking the string `content` for the text *Opps*. If it can be found, meaning `indexOf` did not return -1, then do something, else if it cannot be found do something else.

Hope this helps.